# What's wrong with my code for leetcode 2246?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I am looking at LeetCode problem [2246. Longest Path With Different Adjacent Characters](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-path-with-different-adjacent-characters/):

> You are given a tree (i.e. a connected, undirected graph that has no cycles) rooted at node 0 consisting of n nodes numbered from 0 to n - 1. The tree is represented by a 0-indexed array parent of size n, where parent[i] is the parent of node i. Since node 0 is the root, parent[0] == -1.
>
> You are also given a string s of length n, where s[i] is the character assigned to node i.
>
> Return the length of the longest path in the tree such that no pair of adjacent nodes on the path have the same character assigned to them.

This is my code:

```
function longestPath(parent: number[], s: string): number {
  const childrenMap: Record<number, number[]> = {}
  for (let node = 0; node < parent.length; node++) {
    const parentNode = parent[node]
    childrenMap[parentNode] = childrenMap[parentNode] ?? []
    childrenMap[parentNode].push(node)
  }
  let max = 0
  const dfs = (node = 0, parentNode = -1): number => {
    if (s[node] === s[parentNode]) {
      max = Math.max(max, dfs(node, -1))
      return 0
    }

    const [a = 0, b = 0] = (childrenMap[node] ?? []).map((child) => dfs(child, node))
      .sort((la, lb) => lb - la)
    max = Math.max(max, 1 + a + b)
    return a + 1
  }
  dfs()
  return max
}

console.log(
  longestPath(
    [-1, 56, 10, 79, 52, 0, 37, 39, 127, 125, 116, 52, 95, 131, 105, 55, 55, 52, 87, 35, 43, 130, 87, 103, 8, 73, 8, 116, 4, 43, 60, 104, 116, 118, 78, 9, 133, 139, 7, 127, 96, 28, 52, 79, 78, 36, 102, 134, 100, 104, 47, 127, 129, 77, 121, 133, 10, 58, 104, 55, 69, 73, 107, 9, 139, 79, 52, 72, 130, 78, 112, 43, 14, 4, 120, 9, 139, 118, 52, 52, 73, 82, 79, 58, 121, 80, 139, 10, 25, 74, 10, 123, 134, 112, 40, 80, 108, 128, 5, 52, 43, 31, 10, 42, 79, 139, 86, 58, 3, 118, 117, 21, 4, 79, 45, 26, 5, 122, 102, 13, 88, 139, 108, 118, 116, 10, 58, 32, 80, 125, 121, 105, 116, 104, 82, 131, 39, 10, 126, 125],
    'vodpyvpjmogqvwnibqasbulkfbfugvtlpdtsmydrbrekavkhifoypepbcnzpmasbnlrfqgdhnmvhldsrogjsntummchcftzrnycichziopmphfqwqdsihoywdpqqkyvzrhbqorwrkmns',
  ),
)
```

It outputs 13, but the expected output is 17.

When I replace

```js
 max = Math.max(max, dfs(node, -1))
```

with

```js
max = Math.max(dfs(node, -1), max)
```

the answer will be right (17). I can't tell the difference... What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your `dfs` changes `max` in two places:

```
  max = Math.max(
    max,
    dfs(node, -1),
  )
...
max = Math.max(max, 1 + a + b)
return a + 1
```

So the order in which you call `dfs` as an argument to `Math.max` can affect things:

1. If you call `dfs` first, it will change `max` and the second argument passed to `Math.max` will be the changed value, so it will compare with the correct value that was changed by the recursive `dfs` calls.
2. If you call `dfs` second, it will copy `max`, call `dfs` then compare it with the old `max`, with the value it had before the recursive call.

Solution:

1. The best thing you can do is not mutate state external to `dfs`: make `dfs` return what you need and use that returned value, don't rely on an external variable. You seem to already be returning something from `dfs`, so it shouldn't be too hard to get rid of mutating `max`.
2. That can be messy in some cases (but not yours), in those cases at least don't put the recursive call as a parameter. Do it like this:

   ```
   const dfsResult = dfs(node, -1)
   max = Math.max(max, dfsResult)
   ```